# How to return the result of a mysqli_query so I can use it in another function?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to return the user's id number from the database but I can't figure out how to return the result of the query. I used to use mysql_result() so what would I need to do now that I'm using mysqli?

```
function user_id_from_username($username){
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");

return (what?);
}
```

Comment: i'm not looking to select it from the database. I know how to do that. I'm try to pass the query result back from a function so it can be used in other functions

Comment: how is that not selecting the data? you cant use the data with out selecting it.

Comment: I've already selected the data. I just dont know how to return it from the function

Comment: no you haven't, you have run a query, there is no 'selected' data in the code posted.

Comment: well then how do I select the data if you don't mind me asking. i'm sorry. i'm just trying to figure this out

Comment: My username is `735Tesla' OR  ''=''; DROP TABLE users; SELECT * FROM users WHERE ''='`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't reaped one of the main benefits of moving from `mysql` to `mysqli`, which is using prepared statements to parameterize your queries and protect yourself from injection.

```
$query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT user_id FROM `users` WHERE username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query, $userid);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($query);
//$userid is now user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

check this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php for myqli_query usage. and this http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php on how to get the values from the result.